# Error with pandas: pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

when I run this script it does not work and I don't know why. Can you help me?

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = pd.read_csv(url)
print(data1)
```

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\script.py", line 4, in <module>
    data1 = pd.read_csv(url)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 401, in _read
    data = parser.read()
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 939, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1508, in read
   data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas\parser.c:10415)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 870, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas\parser.c:10691)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 924, in pandas.parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas\parser.c:11437)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 911, in pandas.parser.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas\parser.c:11308)
  File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 2024, in pandas.parser.raise_parser_error (pandas\parser.c:27037)
pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 45 fields in line 49, saw 46
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is separator?

Comment: What is the url? What does the data look like? You really expect others to help out when so little information is provided?

Comment: @Yorian they are confidential data. I can't give you the url.

Comment: No one is going to steal your data. Substitute it with some dummy data. We just need to see the layout, we don't care about the contents.

Comment: In line 49 you probably have a separator inside a string field, the field should probably be quoted.

Comment: @Teudimundo I can't even modify the data because they are stored on an external server

Comment: You can read it and download locally then modify them, or at least trying to understand the issue and whether you can preprocess the data before feeding it to pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that it is not possible to tell.
I suggest to download PyCharm, and run the code in debugging mode, going step by step to see where is the possible problem.

See the [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

in pandas handle, you should pass in the location of the csv.

Example:
pd.read_csv(location.of.archive)
Like: 
pd.read_csv(myfile.csv)

That's all!